# PrestaShop 1.7 You are not allowed to disable the module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I've been trying to upload a module which works perfectly on 1.6 version, but when I try to upload it on a 1.7 Version I get the next error -  check Screenshots.

I've searched for the error everywhere, but can't find an fix to it, pls help.

[image: Screenshot error1]

[image: Screenshot error2]

Comment: Have you fresh (1.7) install or upgraded your Prestashop?

Answer (score 1):

Remove folder with module name from modules folder - you already have folder with this name there.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible that your module is in development mode and you have the buggy sql query in sql/install.php or sql/uninstall.php in your module folder. This happened in my case.

Answer (score 0):

module class name must be the same as the module name, like:

```
class myNextModule extends Module{

public function __construct(){
    $this->name = 'myNextModule';
...
```

If not, this throws 'Module is not a valid module name' error during installation.
Had the same problem, after correction installation finished successfully.
(Prestashop 1.7.6)

Comment: That is not the problem, class name is the same as in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try [disable debug mode](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/575132-how-to-enable-debug-mode-on-prestashop-17-and-older-versions-turn-on-error-reporting-blank-page/). It's working in my case:

```php
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_')) {
    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
}
```